# How to read a Kivy.properties.NumericProperty value in my code at a specific point

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

So basically I have a kivy project in which,I have a layout that I use in many classes,as such..I have made in custom and put it in a separate file so I can just reference it from different parts of my code.

Snippet:

```
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<CustLayout>:
    #code here

''')

class CustLayout(BoxLayout):
    t_length = NumericProperty(0)
    my_len = 0
    print(my_len)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Silvertable,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(t_length=self.on_t_length)
        #This statement is executed after all other prints
        print(self.t_length)

    def on_t_length(self,instance,length):
        #I'd like to get kv file value before the next line
        self.my_len = length
    print(my_len)
```

My kiv file:

```
#:import Silvertable silvertables.Silvertable

#chunk of code
BoxLayout:
    Silvertable:
        t_length: 5
```

Here,I DO get the value but unfortunately **too late**.That is,I get the value after the program has finished.`my_len` Doesn't change it's still 0

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We cannot determine what is happening without an MCVE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Bind Kivy Properties

The value of `my_len` is 0 (zero) because the `print()` functions were executed first before the `run()` method.

The value of `my_len` did change from 0 to 5 as per binding on property of `t_length`.

Please refer to the example and trace for details.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<CustLayout>:
    t_length: 5
''')


class CustLayout(BoxLayout):
    t_length = NumericProperty(0)
    my_len = 0
    print("\tCustLayout.class level-start: my_len=", my_len)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CustLayout,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print("\nCustLayout.__init__:")
        self.bind(t_length=self.on_t_length)
        #This statement is executed after all other prints
        print("\tself.t_length=", self.t_length)
        print("\tself.my_len=", self.my_len)

    def on_t_length(self, instance, length):
        print("\nCustLayout.on_t_length:")
        #I'd like to get kv file value before the next line
        self.my_len = length
        print("\tself.my_len=", self.my_len)

    print("\tCustLayout.class level-end: my_len=", my_len)


class TestBindProperty(App):

    def build(self):
        print("\nTestBindProperty.build:")
        return CustLayout()

    def on_stop(self):
        print("\tTestBindProperty.on_stop: my_len=", self.root.my_len)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestBindProperty().run()
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - App startup: my_len=0]
[image: Img02 - on_t_length: my_len changed from 0 to 5]
[image: Img03 - on_stop: my_len=5]

Comment: ,For the life of me I still don't get why it wasn't working before but you made it work somehow..thanks mate,I just started with kivy so this might be a simple thing but boy did I get a headache there